# how to duplicate the code $ _GET on page 1 to page 2 automatically using the button click

Tags: php

how to use duplicate `$_GET` code?

 
 example: `site.com/page1.php?id=123` using the **click button** to page 2 which id is the same as page1 
 
for example: `site.com/page1.php?id=123` use clik button to `site.com/page2.php?id=123`

 
I want id **123** automatically follow on page2

Comment: Updated formatting

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to generate the page 2 link with the same GET url params in a link.

This function takes an associtive array (like the `$_GET` superglobal) and converts it into a query string (like `id=123&x=....`). So append this to your link like (remember to add a `?`):

```
$queryParams = http_build_query($_GET);

$pageLink = "page2.php?" . $queryParams;

echo "<a src="$pageLink">Page 2</a>";
```

Then on your page2.php file you can access it in your $_GET superglobal:

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

Comment: give me an example of the php code page1 and page2? please :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - the code example I've showed generates a link that points to the other page including the query parameters. On this other page you should be able to access the contents with `$_GET`

Comment: for example like this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rg_zwK_sSEY - taken the id back rg_zwK_sSEY to ( site.com/page1.php?id=rg_zwK_sSEY ) - then on the code button - <button onclick = "location.href = 'othersite.com/page2.php?id=rg_zwK_sSEY'" type = "button"> play now </button>

 - on play now button url, insert link site.com or othersite.com/page2.php?id=rg_zwK_sSEY
 - id ( rg_zwK_sSEY ) automatically follow to page2

Answer (score 0):

```html
for example like this
<br><br>
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<b>rg_zwK_sSEY</b>
<br><br>taken the id back rg_zwK_sSEY to site.com/page1.php?id=rg_zwK_sSEY
<br><br>then on the code button
<br><br><button onclick = "location.href = 'othersite.com/page2.php?id=rg_zwK_sSEY'" type = "button"> play now </button>

<br><br>on play now button url, insert link site.com or othersite.com/page2.php?id=rg_zwK_sSEY
<br><br>id <b>(rg_zwK_sSEY)</b> automatically follow to page2
```